# Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus: The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I've got a service bus topic triggered function which gets triggered whenever some data is pushed to the topic.

The function looks something like this:

```
[FunctionName("funcGetServiceBusEntities")]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("sbtopic", "sbsub", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]Message message, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter, ILogger log)
{  
   // perform processing on the data

   //...

   //...

   // Complete since we don't want to process the message again
   await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);

   //...
}
```

I' m not sure why I'm getting this error:

> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus: The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue. Reference:ab88d42f-5fed-4392-983a-921cc6eab776, TrackingId:7664c851-9f29-4b4f-a334-4038e0921810_B11, SystemTracker:sb-dev:Topic:sbtopic|sbsub, Timestamp:2020-03-31T12:09:32.

Is the implementation of `CompleteAsync` wrong?

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127001/the-lock-supplied-is-invalid-either-the-lock-expired-or-the-message-has-alread

Comment: When the message is be triggered, the message will be removed from the service bus topic. Any update? Can you mark my answer to end this question? Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you faced now:

[image]

Please notice that after triggered the message will be removed. So you don't need to tag it and don't worry about process the message again. It has already been removed.